# position of virtual keyword in function declaration

Tags: c++, virtual, keyword, function-declaration

Does it make any difference whether I place the `virtual` keyword in a function declaration before or after the return value type?

```
virtual void DoSomething() = 0;
void virtual DoSomething() = 0;
```

Found the `void virtual` syntax while refactoring some legacy code, and was wondering that it is compiling at all...

Comment: If it compiled and ran as expected then I guess it works. Your question should be: Is this a compiler quirk or is it standards compliant behaviour?

Comment: Is there something that prevents you from trying?

Comment: I tried both and don't _see_ any difference. Which doesn't mean there is _no_ difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both the statements are equivalent.
But the 1st one is more conventional. Because, generally  **mandatory fields** are kept **closest** to any syntax (i.e. the function prototype in your example).

`virtual` is an optional keyword (it's needed for pure `virtual` though). However return type (here `void`) is a mandatory keyword, which is always required. So people keep `virtual` on the left most side and the `return` type a little closer to the function signature.

Another example: I generally see that in below code 1st syntax is more popular for the same reason:

```
const int i = 0;  // 1
int const i = 0;  // 2
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference between the two, [C++ grammar](http://www.nongnu.org/hcb) allows virtual keyword to appear both before and after return type. It's just common practice to place it first in the declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Both the formats work but the standard specifys the first format.

Reference:
**C++03 7.1 Specifiers**

> The specifiers that can be used in a declaration are

```
   decl-specifier:
         storage-class-specifier
         type-specifier
         function-specifier
         friend
         typedef

     decl-specifier-seq:
           decl-specifier-seqopt decl-specifier
```

And further `function-specifier` are explained in,

**7.1.2 Function specifiers**

Function-specifiers can be used only in function declarations.

```
 function-specifier:
     inline
     virtual
     explicit
```

Comment: But the standard doesn't say anything about the *order* of the specifiers, correct? So it's actually _not_ defined in the standard which of the two alternatives to use.

Comment: @RonaldMcBean: Yes, I was looking up for a specific citation but couldn't find any.

Comment: +1 for the standard quotes. I din't know standard specifies all such things also, which we usually take for granted. :0

Answer (score -1):

tested just now:

compiles both ways.

usualy virtual is put before return type.

read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0y01k918%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: That is no answer to my question. I know how to do it correctly, I want to know whether it makes any difference.

Comment: It isnt a rule. just programming practise